# Using cookies to consume other web services from server

Tags: java, web-services, cookies

I have a backend server written in Java that contains services used by a mobile app that I have also created. I am using Appcelerator as a 3rd party push notification service and they require a user to be logged in in order to send push notifications.

Here is the flow of events that I would like to have happen:

1. The user logs in to my app (could also log in to Appcelerator here)
2. The user does something that should send a push notification
3. The request gets sent to MY server to send the push notification
4. My server makes the request to Appcelerator to send a push notification

Somewhere in that process, there needs to be an authentication with Appcelerator. Currently, I'm just using my credentials with Appcelerator as sort of an admin and I'm authenticating before each unique push notification is sent. However, this means authenticating before each push notification which will significant increase the time it takes.

There are two possible solutions I have identified but I am unsure if either is possible:

1. Have each user of my mobile app authenticate with Appcelerator when first logging in and save that some how on my server so that when they make a request to my server, I use their cookie to authenticate. (This seems insecure.)
2. Persist my authentication with Appcelerator past 1 request to my server. (This seems to be the easier of the two solutions but I'm unsure if it is possible/the right way to do it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I am doing user management on my server, it does not make sense to also do it through Appcelerator. I previously thought that if I wanted to use Appcelerator as a push notification service, that I had to create users through their service as well.

However, I now realize that there are two sections in their Push Notification API.

- subscribe
- unsubscribe
- notify

and

- subscribeToken
- unsubscribeToken
- notifyToken

The latter group, uses the pushToken from the device, which is not related to Appcelerator in any way. With those methods, you do not need to have Appcelerator users as you can just send the push notifications to the device tokens.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! can you please provide an example on how to send the notifications to the device tokens? You are doing this from the server right?